# Scroll content when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a Sign In form in my app (just an `EditText` for email and another one for password and below its a button ) and because keyboard hides password when focus is on email, I want the user to be able to scroll with his finger and not just click the action Next button in keyboard.

So I decided to add a `ScrollView` and because I want the content to be aligned to bottom, I added a `LinearLayout` as a parent of the `ScrollView` and added gravity bottom for the `Scrollview`.

The xml code for the layout is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_name" android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_medium" android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:hint="Enter email" android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white" android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password" android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_medium"
            android:hint="@string/sign_in_password_hint" android:inputType="textPassword" android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signin_submit"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_button" android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_normal"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sign_in"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large_app" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large_app"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that when one edittext gets focus then the layout it just "flashes" all the content above the keyboard and scrolling is not working at all.

Any help on how to enable smooth scrolling ?

Comment: Im not sure if it will work but try adding this property in the activity declaration inside your AndroidManifest.xml: 

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already have this inside my manifest file.

Comment: ScrollView does not make sense remove it and add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustSpan" to your activity in manifeast

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use to scrollview. You just add this line in your mainfest file in side activity tag.
**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the children inside of ScrollView inside another LinearLayout.